# Sum a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list where each element is a 5*5 matrix. Eg

```
[[1]]   
           V1          V2          V3          V4          V5      
      [1,]   0.000000   46.973700   21.453500  338.547000   10.401600 
      [2,]  43.020500    0.000000  130.652000  840.526000   56.363700 
      [3,]  12.605600  173.238000    0.000000  642.075000   19.628100 
      [4,] 217.946000  626.368000  481.329000    0.000000  642.341000 
      [5,] 217.946000  626.368000  481.329000    0.000000  642.341000 
[[2]]   
           V1          V2          V3          V4          V5      
      [1,]   0.000000   47.973700   21.453500  338.547000   10.401600 
      [2,]  143.020500    0.000000  130.652000  840.526000   56.363700 
      [3,]  312.605600  17.238000    0.000000  642.075000   19.628100 
      [4,]  17.946000  126.368000  481.329000    0.000000  642.341000
      [5,] 217.946000  626.368000  481.329000    0.000000  642.341000  
...
```

How can I use an apply-like function to sum matrix [1] to [n],  and return a 5*5 matrix as a result (each element is a sum of the corresponding elements in each of the matrix in the list) ?

Comment: I suggest you edit your post to give a reproducible example and make clearer what you're after.  An example of what your final result would like like would also be helpful.  In it's current state it will likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My post has been edited.

Comment: Are you summing a list of 5 * 5 matrices? to give a 5 *5 matrix?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use `Reduce`.

```
## dummy data

.list <- list(matrix(1:25, ncol = 5), matrix(1:25, ncol = 5))

Reduce('+', .list)
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    2   12   22   32   42
## [2,]    4   14   24   34   44
## [3,]    6   16   26   36   46
## [4,]    8   18   28   38   48
## [5,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

Comment: That is nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: @GSee   I tried to used the do.call, but it returns an error as "operator needs one or two arguments"

Comment: `do.call` will only work with a list of length 2. I've removed this from the answer.

Comment: What would be the equivalent of '+' to get the max?

Comment: @GabrielMontenegro `pmax` (`pmin` for minimum)

Answer (score 15):

I think @mnel's answer is the more efficient but this is another approach:

```
apply(simplify2array(.list), c(1,2), sum)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   12   22   32   42
[2,]    4   14   24   34   44
[3,]    6   16   26   36   46
[4,]    8   18   28   38   48
[5,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

Comment: Nice trick though in this case Reduce is faster (Reduce is the fastest answer here that extends to multiple correlation matrices in a list).  +1

Comment: And to the contrary of Reduce, it also works with mean instead of +.

Comment: this also gives options like `na.rm`. +1

Answer (score 5):

You could you `do.call` with some monkeying around but it loses its eloquence:

```
.list <- list(matrix(1:25, ncol=5), matrix(1:25,ncol=5), matrix(1:25,ncol=5))

x <- .list[[1]]
lapply(seq_along(.list)[-1], function(i){
    x <<- do.call("+", list(x, .list[[i]]))
})
x
```

Comment: But, then you don't need `do.call`; you could have `x <<- x + .list[[i]]` inside your `lapply`.

Comment: very true.  `Reduce` is much more eloquent though on a bunch of matrices the `lapply` approach may be faster (sometimes the Higher Order Functions suffer speed issues).