# Summing up many matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, sum, printf

Supposed that I have 99 matrix with same column and row length,
and try to sum them up (element by element).

99 matrix are already assigned.

What I want to make is the code of something like below.

```
var <- sprintf("S%02d", 1:99)  # seq. of matrix names
SUM_S <- sum(var)              # S01 + S02 + ... + S99
```

please give me an idea of summing up many matrix in a short code.

Comment: Sadly Richard Scriven has deleted his comment, despite the fact that it was correct and my answer was not. Hopefully he will compose an answer instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641701/sum-a-list-of-matrices

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce` to apply a binary function over a list.

Something like `Reduce("+", lapply(var, function(x) eval(as.name(x))))` , where the `lapply` part is to create a list of all the matrices from the list of variable names in `var`.